# Copy synced videos in/from Dailymotion

Tags: sync, video, dailymotion

Is it possible to access the sync'ed DailyMotion videos somewhere else?

I know they're saved somewhere in the cache (`\mnt\sdcard\Android\data\com.dailymotion.dailymotion\cache\videos`). If you clear the cache, they're gone.

Is it possible to move them to somewhere else, e.g., on your SD card or even PC and watch them there?

Comment: What file format are they in the cache? They could possibly be protected with DRM. Have you tried to open the files in the cache with a video player app (try MX Player)

Comment: File format is unknown - no filename extension. Doesn't open in MX Player.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the cache, and find the file that you want to play. There will be 2 files with the same name, one will be only a few kb, the other will be the video (should be a few MB).

Long press on the file until you get the menu. Then select "open as", then "video", then select a video player.

I used the stock one that comes with the phone even though I have several others I thought I would try that first, and it worked first time (this was on a Galaxy S3).

If they play then copy them where you want, pc etc. You might need to rename the video files (adding the `.mp4` file extension).

Answer (score -1):

I had to rename the file first (added .mp4 to the end). Worked perfectly in MXPlayer

Comment: How does this answer the question?