# "Can't play this video" when trying to play downloaded DailyMotion video

Tags: video, dailymotion

From one of the answer in [Copy synced videos in/from Dailymotion](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44974/copy-synced-videos-in-from-dailymotion),

> Go to the cache, and find the file that you want to play. There will be 2 files with the same name, one will be only a few kb, the other will be the video (should be a few MB).
>
> Long press on the file until you get the menu. Then select "open as", then "video", then select a video player.

I did that process, but when I select "video", after buffering it shows a dialogue that says "Can't play this video".

Any solution to this problem?